# Combining categories for column chart with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a column chart using Highcharts 4.0.4.  The chart plots hourly data.  This looks fine if I'm only plotting a day's worth of data.  If I want to plot a week's or months' worth then the columns get very narrow.  Are there any Highcharts settings that would automatically group/sum columns together when so many hours are being considered.  For example, if I plot a week's worth, it would be preferable if 24 hour's-worth of data was summed to create daily columns, and maybe weekly for a month's worth of data (although no month is exactly 4 weeks).

Of course I can process the data in these situations myself, but am wondering if Highcharts has built in functionality to do this.  I have looked at the API notes on dataGrouping (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping) but can't figure it out, or even if it is possible for column charts.

UPDATE:

I've tried adding the following to my series definition (note that this is coffeescript):

```
series.type = "column"
series.dataGrouping =
    approximation: "sum"
    enabled: true
    groupPixelWidth: 5
    units: [
       [ 'hour', [1,2,3,6,12]]
       ,
       [ 'day', [1]]    
       ,
       [ 'week', [1]]
       ,
       [ 'month', [1,3,6]]
       ,        
       [ 'year', [1]]
    ]
```

But i don't see any difference when I plot 24hrs, 7 days, 1 month, i.e., each hour is plotted separately with no grouping as in the example below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The dataGrouping is available only in the Highstock, not in the highcharts.

Comment: Ah thanks... that would explain it.  Any equivalent functionality in HighCharts?